# ActionController InvalidAuthenticityToken in Api::V1::UsersController#create

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going to create restful API using Ruby on Rails.   I want to create, delete, show and update data.  All of them should have to be JSON to get it in Android devices.  I'm also using Postman to check my APIs.
This is what I've done:

My Controller:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def show
        respond_with User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        user=User.new(user_params)
        if user.save
            render json: user, status: 201
        else
            render json: {errors: user.errors}, status: 422
        end
    end

    def update
        user=User.find(params[:id])
        if user.update(user_params)
            render json: user, status:200
        else
        render json: {erros: user.errors},status: 422
        end

    end

    def destroy
        user=User.find(params[:id])
        user.destroy
        head 204
    end

    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

and this is my route file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api, defaults:{ format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
    resources :users, :only=>[:show,:create,:update,:destroy]   
    end
  end
end
```

and also added following code to my Gemfile:

```
gem "devise"
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

I don't know why when I want to create via postman I get the following error:

```
ActionController InvalidAuthenticityToken in Api::V1::UsersController#create
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to make the following change in application_controller.rb

Change

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

to

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

**EDIT**

Better way is to skip the authentication for a specific controller

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  respond_to :json
  # ...
end
```

Comment: The author of the question hasn't stated the error yet.  I'm curious how you were able to know how to solve the problem.

Comment: I totally missed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### In application_controller.rb

For **Web Controllers**:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

For **API Controllers**:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

You can also choose when to run this validation with the **prepend** parameter (default value of this option is false)

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, prepend: true
```

Like the documentation says

> *This is useful you want your forgery protection to depend on other callbacks, like authentication methods (Oauth vs Cookie auth)*